# How to unsubscribe gundb on event function?

Tags: gun

How do I stop events triggered by `gun('something').on()` for gundb a handler (to unsubscribe) so it would stop update the list or changes to the list.

Answer (score 1):

In 0.5 and above you simply call `.off()`.

However, you can't in previous versions. There is a work around though, here is how to do it:

```
var options = {};

gun.get('something').on(callback, options);

options.on.off()
```

Basically, the event emitter gets attached to the options object as the `on` property, which you can call `.off()` later. I hope this helps!

Comment: I see. Where would it be posted?

Answer (score 0):

On the callback to the `.on` call you get a few arguments.
`(value, key, message, onEvent) => void`
The last of these arguments contains it's own `.off` function that specifically removes the listener that the onEvent was handed to.

A relatively simple solution would then be:

```js
let off = ()=>{};
chain.on((value, key, message, evt)=>{
  callback(value, key, message, evt);
  off = ()=> evt.off();
});
```